# .xib files not showing up in MonoTouch

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

Right after building for the simulator I got an error message saying MonoTouch stopped unexpectedly and it shut down. So I closed Xcode and reloaded both. Now, I can't see my .xib files inside the MonoTouch file tree. I can open the .xib files directly in Xcode, but none of the resources need for the files are visible (for instance, images stored in the Resource folder).

How can I get these .xib files associated correctly again?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this. Had to go back and add each of my existing .xib files back into the project by right clicking on the appropriate folder and then finding the .xib file in the project folder. Once I added them all back, everything worked as expected